# Problems with Datatables and unwanted Horizontal scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

Im hoping this is a fairly simple problem.

Im trying to use Datatables to create a table without any horizontal scrolling. The table has some long data rows which I need to keep on one line and hide the overflow.

It seems like I'm missing something fairly basic with datatables here, but I can't seem to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar when the table gets a vertical scrollbar.

http://jsfiddle.net/FBpLA/3/

There are two tables (identical data), both are initialised very simply.

```
$('#mytable').dataTable({
    bFilter: false,
    bInfo: false,
    bPaginate: false,
});

$('#mytable2').dataTable({
    bFilter: false,
    bInfo: false,
    bPaginate: false,
    sScrollY: '150px'
});
```

The styles for the page are fairly straight forward

```
body {
     height:100%;
     color: #000000;
     font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
     font-size: 10pt;
     background-color: #B4D4EC;
 }
 .main-panel {
     display:block;
     background:white;
     padding:20px;
     height: 100%;
     position:absolute;
     width: 700px;
     top: 139px;
     bottom: 110px;
 }
 th {
     text-align:left;
 }
 td {
     border-spacing:0;
     white-space:nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     -ms-text-overflow:ellipsis;
 }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the end the best solution was to set the width of the inner table to:

```
table-layout:fixed;
width: 98% !important;
```

All solutions listed here had undesirable cropping behavior. Limiting the table width in this way also allowed me to dynamically adjust the height of the table such that the horizontal scrollbar can appear or disappear on demand without introducing an horizontal scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/FBpLA/15/

Comment: I couldn't find an element with class `dataTables_scrollBody` in my DOM (using DataTables with the Responsive extension); I applied your styling to the `dataTable` class instead, and it worked.

Answer (score 11):

```
.dataTables_scrollBody
{
 overflow-x:hidden !important;
 overflow-y:auto !important;
}
```

this worked for me for all of my tables. 
This was also only an issue with firefox and IE, chrome handled it just fine to begin with.

Comment: Worked fine; didn't need overflow-y. +1

Answer (score 6):

You can just add `overflow-x: hidden;` to the `.dataTables_scrollBody` if you can't find something that fixes it natively in the script. Unfortunately, you'll probably also need to use `!important` to raise its specificity higher than the inline styles applied to the element already.

http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/FBpLA/12/

Comment: I would add that I found the best place to do this is in the dataTables.css file that accompanies the script.  I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why in some browsers the scroll wrapper appears and in others it doesn't.  I ended up using this and I have seen no bad side effects as of yet.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the css tag `overflow-x:hidden;`  to remove the horizontal scrollbar on the table with id `mytable2`.

```
#mytable2 
{    
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden; 
}
```

However, if you use `table-layout:fixed` this won't work, a majority of the browsers will treat the overflow in their naturual behaviour rather than watching the css.

Some info on `table-layout:fixed` by Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FBpLA/9/

Answer (score 0):

Datatables by default calculates the width of the table and applies it as an inline style to the table element (this is called [autoWidth](https://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth)). Thus, you may have issues in forcing the table to respect any width settings you provide without disabling this.  (See [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/887/table-width).) Set `autoWidth: false` in the table settings to disable it.

You can then apply width stylings to the `dataTables_scrollBody` or table. For example:

```
.dataTables_scrollBody {
    width: 98%
}
```

This should prevent any cropping resulting from disabling horizontal scrolling while ensuring the inline width doesn't mess up settings you provide. You can also avoid using `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit css atributes od the div contains the table label before initialize the table.

```
$('.table-div-container').css({'overflow-x': 'hidden','border': 'none'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this code works to me... jst have a look

```
.table-responsive {
min-height: .01%;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```