# Avoid Horizontal Scrolling with JQuery DataTable plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can I set the column width in a table that uses [JQuery DataTable](http://datatables.net/) plugin to avoid the horizontal scroll ?

What I've tried

```
var table = $(data.datatable.container).DataTable({
                    dom: "frtiS",
                    "columnDefs": [{ "width": "5%", "targets": 0 }],
                    autoWidth: false,                    
                    scrollX": false,
                    scrollY: "250px",
                    paging: true,
                    order: true,
                    language: {
                        info: data.datatable.info,
                        search: data.datatable.language.search,
                        zeroRecords: data.datatable.language.zeroRecords,
                        emptyTable: data.datatable.language.emptyTable,
                        infoEmpty: data.datatable.language.infoEmpty,
                        infoFiltered: data.datatable.language.infoFiltered,
                        loadingRecords: data.datatable.language.loadingRecords,
                        processing: data.datatable.language.processing,
                        paginate: {
                            first: data.datatable.language.paginate.first,
                            previous: data.datatable.language.paginate.previous,
                            next: data.datatable.language.paginate.next,
                            last: data.datatable.language.paginate.last
                        }
                    }
                });
```

But doesn't work

[image]

**TABLE**

```
<table id="tabelaVendedorPorEstado" style="overflow-x: hidden;" class="table tabelaListagemVendedores">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Vendedores</th>
                    <th>Valor</th>
                    <th>%</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- Some TR TD here -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with Datatables and unwanted Horizontal scrollbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950043/problems-with-datatables-and-unwanted-horizontal-scrollbar)

Comment: @StanimirStoyanov Hide the scroll isn't enough, I need resize the column width to avoid the scroll and not just hide them

Comment: hi, did you find a solution to this issue? i'm using DataTables with Bootstrap and the table keeps showing an horizontal scrollbar when inside a "responsive-table" div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to fix it with pure css like this:

```
div.container {
    width: 95%;
}
```

Match your actual container class for the DataTables, also verify that you don't have fixed widths. Your first column seems to be much wider than it should.

Comment: This occurs only if I set vertical scrolling option. Seems that the column's avoid a break line.

Comment: Did you try to do something like `width="20%"` or `width="200"` for the first column?

Comment: If it is possible, do a jsfiddle example with the issue, because I can't reproduce it based on the code you posted here.