# How can I disable scrollX in DT::datatable

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, dt

I have a table that I render `using DT::datatable`. I would like to have a Y scrolling but no X scrolling, and no wraping of long lines either.
I found the `Scroller` extension **but I cannot disable X scroll**.

example:

````
---
title: "dt_render"
output: html_document
---

```{r render dt, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(DT)
DF = data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rep("a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long line", 100))
datatable(
  DF, 
  extensions = c('Buttons', 'Scroller'), 
  options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = c('colvis','csv'),
    deferRender = TRUE,
    scrollY = 200,
    scroller = TRUE,
    scrollX = FALSE
  ),
  class = 'display compact nowrap'
)

```
````

output:

[image: output]

Comment: `scroller = FALSE`  and `lengthMenu = c(7, 10, 15, 20)`  solved it on my pc.

Comment: not working for me

Comment: I found `overflow-y:hidden` choice in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950043/problems-with-datatables-and-unwanted-horizontal-scrollbar) question. But I don't know how to implement that style in R. Maybe you know the trick.

Comment: ok, you can just add it to a styles.css file and add css: styles.css bellow html_document in the yaml header. It works in that it removes the scrolling but then the y line is not large enough, I nee to see the whole y line

Answer (score 0):

The following solves it.

**I am not happy with the `width = 1000` that seems bad, is there something better ?**

````
---
title: "dt_render"
output: html_document
css: styles.css
---

```{r render dt, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(DT)
DF = data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rep("a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long line", 100))
datatable(
  DF, 
  extensions = c('Buttons', 'Scroller', 'KeyTable'), 
  width = 1000,
  options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = c('colvis','csv'),
    scrollY = 200,
    scroller = TRUE,
    keys = TRUE    
  ),
  class = 'display compact nowrap'
)

```
````

with in the css file

```
.dataTables_scrollBody
{
 overflow-x:hidden !important;
 overflow-y:auto !important;
}
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

In the css file (or in the datatables.css lines of Scroller extension):

1. to disable the x scrolling, I added:

   ```css
   .dataTables_scrollBody{
     overflow-x:hidden !important;
     overflow-y:auto !important;
    }
   ```
2. to disable the wraping of long lines, I commented the lines:

   ```css
     /* div.dts tbody th,div.dts tbody td{
        white-space:nowrap
        } */
   ```